# Убрать часть окна с названием приложения в Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать верхнюю часть окна (указано стрелкой) в Pygame? Без использования Fullscreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заголовок окна pygame  можно убрать с помощью "pygame.NOFRAME".

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), pygame.NOFRAME)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]